# Does this code create segmentation fault error?

Tags: c, malloc

I made this code for re-coding `printf`.
`ft_strdup` does the same thing as the `strdup`.

```
static char *ft_make_final_test(const char *str)
{
    char    *res;
    size_t  j;
    if (!(res = ft_strdup("")))
        return (0);
    j = 0;
    while (*str)
    {
        if (*str == '%')
        {

        }
        else
        {
            res[j] = *str;
            j++;
        }
        str++;
    }
    res[j] = '\0';
    return (res);
}
```

I tested for very very long string and it comes with no segmentation fault or something. But I still feel anxious. Is it safe for any other string? Or should I do something?

Comment: What does `ft_strdup` do? Please provide a [complete minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If it does the same as `strdup` then yeah your code has undefined behaviour if it tries to write to more than one character into `res`.

Comment: If the function allocated memory for the string `""` then it is not safe to copy the passed string (omitting any `'%'`), which is of unknown length. Even if you get no segfault while testing. From the edit, you will have allocated 1-byte buffer to `res`.

Comment: The question "does it cause segfault?" should be answered by you. Most even quite evil mishandling of pointers and memory does not reliably cause a segfault (life would be too easy then). But if you show a MRE, people might spot evil things you do.

Comment: @kaylum thanks for comments. Should I use realloc or something?

Comment: Depends on the requirements of your task. If you don't mind potentially wasting a few bytes then just do `malloc(strlen(str)+1)`

Comment: `strdup` is not the right function to use here. Replace it with `malloc` as per the previous comment.

Comment: Anyway, depending on what will be in the empty `{}` of `if (*str == '%')` there is more work to be done regarding the size of the `res` buffer, possibly reallocating space with `realloc`.

Comment: As a note, the "Works on my machine" test is not very reliable. You need to look for undefined behaviour, which means knowing a lot of sometimes esoteric rules. Tools like Valgrind can help analyze your code and show faults.